# Issues running simple Camel Restlet demo project?

Tags: java, spring, maven, apache-camel, restlet

Hi i am trying to run a simple project in Camel Restlet but when i run it on tomcat 7 i get the following error?

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 7 in XML document from class path resource [camel-context.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'camelContext'. One of '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":description, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":import, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":alias, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":bean, WC[##other:"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"]}' is expected.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:397)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:282)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:204)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:976)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1653)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'camelContext'. One of '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":description, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":import, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":alias, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":bean, WC[##other:"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"]}' is expected.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:131)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:384)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:318)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:417)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:3182)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1806)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:705)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:400)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2756)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:235)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:284)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388)
    ... 27 more
```

The project doesn't do much it just returns a Hi to the username in the get URL. Attaching the other files in the project. I am new to this and please let me know what i am doing wrong, if there is anything i have added which is not required.

Here is my **camel-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

     <camelContext>
<route>
<from uri="restlet:/demo/{yourname}" />
<transform>
<simple>Hi ${header.yourname}</simple>
</transform>
</route>
</camelContext>
</beans>
```

This is my **web.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>A demo on REST API with Camel Restlet</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:camel-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>RestletServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.restlet.ext.spring.SpringServerServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>org.restlet.component</param-name>
            <param-value>RestletComponent</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>RestletServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rs/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

And finally my **POM.xml**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>examples</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.0</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>crestlet-demo</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Camel :: Demo :: Restlet :: JDBC</name>
    <description>A demo on REST API with Camel Restlet</description>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
        <id>maven-restlet</id>
        <name>Public online Restlet repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.restlet.org</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
        </dependency>        
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-restlet</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.spring</artifactId>
            <version>${restlet-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

I will be calling this using the following URL:-

```
http://localhost:8080/mywebapp/rs/demo/yourname
```

Please let me know if i am doing anything wrong here..

Answer (score 1):

The error is because your Spring XML file does not reference the Camel schema, so it does not understand what **camelContext** is.

As per the [Camel Spring documentation](https://camel.apache.org/spring.html) you need add Camel to the **schemaLocation** list and either create a camel namespace prefix or explicitly mention it.

Step 1: Update **beans**

`<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
      http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">`

Step 2: Use `<camel:camelContext>` instead of `<camelContext>`

Comment: Ok, Thanks, Let me try

Comment: Update the comel-context.xml now i am getting the following error:- org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 6 in XML document from class path resource [camel-context.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'route'. One of '{"http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring":properties, "http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring":propertyPlaceholder, "http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring":package,

Comment: can't post the full stack in comments

Comment: You would also need "camel:" prefix for all of the XML items inside camel context too. The other option which may be easier is to just use this: `<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">`

Comment: ok, it fixed it thank for that, but now i am getting org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'camel-1:beanPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.expression.spel.support.StandardEvaluationContext.setBeanResolver(Lorg/springframework/expression/BeanResolver;)V

Comment: Let me post my updtad POm

Comment: I have posted the updated POM in y question, Please if you could look at it

Comment: I cheked my delloyment directory and in the lIb i have 2 jars:-spring-expression-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar and spring-expression-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar

Comment: So seems like an issue in my POM

Comment: ok, that got resolved after mvn clean..And one more thing i was missing in camelcontext.cml was:- <bean id="RestletComponent" class="org.restlet.Component" />
 
<bean id="RestletComponentService" class="org.apache.camel.component.restlet.RestletComponent">
  <constructor-arg index="0">
    <ref bean="RestletComponent" />
  </constructor-arg>
</bean>

Comment: After these all worked well. Testingit out in case i find any issues